# Xamarin Forms Html Display Issues

Tags: html, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to display html in my page, I am using the **TextType="Html"** for the label but it is not working, it is displaying it as normal text. I thought it would be simple as I saw many documentations using it without any issues.

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Bufib.Views.Others.DoaaPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView x:Name="parent" Padding="10">
            <StackLayout x:Name="stackLyt">
                <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activityIndicator" IsRunning="True" IsVisible="false"/>
                <Label x:Name="doaaContentLbl" TextType="Html" FontSize="Medium" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

CS:

```
 private async void Init()
    {
        ...
        doaaContentLbl.Text = doaa.Content;
    }
```

Comment: where is the HTML you are trying to display?

Comment: @Jason so the problem was that the content was retrieved as (> &gt; < &lt;), so I fixed it